# CCArray "Access violation reading location"

Tags: cocos2d-x

I am using cocos2d-2.0-rc2-x-2.0.1 @ Jun 29 2012 and wrote this

.h

```
...
protected:
CCArray *array;
...
```

.cpp

```
...
bool HelloWorld::init()
{
...
array= CCArray::create(2);
array->addObject(obj1);
array->addObject(obj2);
...
}

void HelloWorld::ccTouchesBegan(CCSet* touches, CCEvent* event)
{
    CCLog("%i", array->count());
}
...
```

and got this:
0xC0000005: Access violation reading location "0xfeeefeee".

in

CCArray.cpp

```
unsigned int CCArray::count()
{
    return data->num;
}
```

Please, help.

Comment: Magic numbers like this 0xfeeefeee usually point to a deallocated object, or out of bounds issue. For example malloc guard and other debugging settings use such patterns to detect buffer overwrites.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

try to call

```
    array->retain()
```

after the create. maybe the array is autorealeased after you leave the function.

but don't forget to release it after you finished.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do this:

```
array = new CCArray();
array->initWithCapacity(3);
```

`create()` returns an `autorelease` CCObject.